# Set background image for UIToolBar

Tags: ios, design-patterns, crash, uitoolbar, uiappearance

I've seen a lot of people doing this:

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:toolBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

For me it doesn't work, because my App crashes and says:

```
-[_UIAppearance setBackgroundImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xab8fe80
```

I already researched and found out that UIAppearance is only available since ios 5, but my simulator is 6.1 and my iPhone too. Also I did this with the NavigationBar which works.

Hope you can help me :) Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

If The `UIToolbar` is contained within a ViewController.

You cannot change the `UIToolbar` within `AppDelegate` if the `UIToolbar` is contained in a ViewController.

Also see here: [IOS 5 unrecognized selector send at appearance proxy for setBackgroundImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702438/ios-5-unrecognized-selector-send-at-appearance-proxy-for-setbackgroundimage)

Read all the comments [iOS5 changing Background of UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312659/ios5-changing-background-of-uitoolbar)

Comment: coz in the comment there is your answer, same thing i posted here. Have a look there and tell me, it that answer worked?

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya you mean a UINavigationController? because it works just fine in UIViewController

Comment: and how can i add a backgroundimage then?

Comment: as you selected the answer, i felt it worked!!! Yuo should not accept any answer unless that helped you.

Comment: Ok :], do you know how or not?

Comment: I dont know, and I need to check in xcode, I dont have mac now :(

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
UIImage* toolbarImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"toolbar_background.png"];
[[UIToolbar appearance] 
    setBackgroundImage: toolbarImage 
    forToolbarPosition: UIToolbarPositionAny
    barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use the appearance proxy, you can set background image to the specific toolar: `[yourToolbar setBackgroundImage: toolbarImage 
    forToolbarPosition: UIToolbarPositionAny
    barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault]`

Answer (score 0):

You should call this method in your app delegate implementation file in the didfinishlaunchingwithoptions: method